# UIGravityBehavior and UICollisionBehavior do not work if center of item is outside of reference view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uikit-dynamics

**EDIT:** I was able to solve this issue based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252216/uidynamicanimator-view-entering-from-outside-of-the-reference-bounds) thread, by setting up a custom boundary, however I would still like to know why doesn't the view fall if its center is outside the reference view.

---

**How do you make a View fall into another view, but stop at the bottom of that view?**

What I noticed is, if the center of the subview (the view to be animated) is outside the superview (reference view), the view won't fall down.

I have a superview with bounds {0, 0, 320, 556}. I have another view, added as subview, sized {320, 556}.

I need to make the subview fall from {0, -456, 320, 556} to {0, 0, 320, 556} (Basically, only a small part of it (like 100 pts) is visible, and it has to fall all the way down to fill the superview.

Here's an illustration of the initial state (the two views should be of equal size)

[image]

Here's the animation code:

```
self.dynamicAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

UIGravityBehavior *gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.subView]];
[self.dynamicAnimator addBehavior:gravity];

UICollisionBehavior *collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[subView]];
collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
[self.dynamicAnimator addBehavior:collision];
```